# .htaccess URL Rewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've never been good at .htaccess, I'm trying to copy and paste some code that worked on another one of my domains and modify it to work here. I will have several rewritten URLs, some static, some dynamic, but I can't even get the simplest of them to work. This one is testable here: http://lindseymotors.com/home

Clearly, index.php is available because if you access http://lindseymotors.com it works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.* [NC]

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
RewriteRule ^home/$ index.php
# When answering, if you could write a statement that would combine
# both of the statements above into one that would be appreciated.
```

As I said, these same conditions worked on another one my domains because I copied the code right over. I asked my server admin to double check everything on his end and it was fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is make sure the use of .htaccess is really on. The easiest way you can check since your server admin says it's fine is to put random text at the top of your .htaccess file. If your .htaccess file is being read and .htaccess files are enabled, it should throw a `500 internal server error`. If not, then they don't have .htaccess files enabled and need to add `AllowOverride All` to the Apache config vhost.

Here is your rule combined into one as you noted. You really don't need the RewriteCond, but I will leave since you were using it previously.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a bunch of random characters to the top of the file and I'm still able to access pages using the correct .php URL. I suppose this means that it's an AllowOverride problem?

Comment: Yes .htaccess is definitely not enabled for your domain/virtualhost. That needs to be changed in your server apache config to `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Thank you. My server admin had a typo, he had "lindsay" instead of "lindsey". Thank you for throwing out that tip to make sure it was in fact a problem with the server.